# How to compute the mean by index of an array column in a dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I'm using Spark 2.2. and I have a basic question about working with `ArrayType`. I didn't find built-in aggregation functions to work with.

Given a `DataFrame` with a column `id` and a column `values` of `ArrayType`.

We want to group by id and then compute the mean value by index.

So given the following input

```
{"id": 1, "values":[1.0, 3.0]}
{"id": 1, "values":[3.0, 7.0]}
{"id": 2, "values":[2.0, 4.0]}
```

We want this output

```
{"id": 1, "values":[2.0, 5.0]}
{"id": 2, "values":[2.0, 4.0]}
```

I've come up with a solution using *UDAF*, cf code below.

Is there a better way (e.g. without using UDAF) in term of performance?

```
  val meanByIndex = new UserDefinedAggregateFunction {
    override def inputSchema: StructType =
      StructType(
        StructField("values", ArrayType(DoubleType)) :: Nil
      )

    override def dataType: DataType = ArrayType(DoubleType)

    override def deterministic: Boolean = true

    override def update(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer, row: Row): Unit = {
      buffer.update(0, buffer.getAs[Long](0) + 1)
      buffer.update(1, sumSeq(buffer.getAs[Seq[Double]](1), row.getAs[Seq[Double]](0))
      )
    }

    override def bufferSchema: StructType =
      StructType(
        StructField("size", LongType) ::
          StructField("sum", ArrayType(DoubleType)) :: Nil
      )

    override def merge(buffer1: MutableAggregationBuffer, buffer2: Row): Unit = {
      buffer1.update(0, buffer1.getAs[Long](0) + buffer2.getAs[Long](0))
      buffer1.update(1, sumSeq(buffer1.getAs[Seq[Double]](1), buffer2.getAs[Seq[Double]](1))
      )
    }

    override def initialize(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer): Unit = {
      buffer.update(0, 0L)
      buffer.update(1, Seq.empty[Double])
    }

    override def evaluate(buffer: Row): Any = {
      buffer.getAs[Seq[Double]](1).map(_ / buffer.getAs[Long](0))
    }

    private def sumSeq(s1: Seq[Double], s2: Seq[Double]) = {
      if (s1.isEmpty)
        s2
      else {
        s1.zip(s2).map { case (v1, v2) => v1 + v2 }
      }
    }
  }
```

[update] regarding the answer of @user6910411, I've compared execution plan.

With UDAF

```
SortAggregate
+- *Sort [id#1 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
   +- Exchange hashpartitioning(id#1, 200)
      +- SortAggregate
         +- *Sort [id#1 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
            +- *FileScan json
```

Without UDAF

```
*HashAggregate
+- Exchange hashpartitioning(id#1, 200)
   +- *HashAggregate
      +- *FileScan json
```

Conclusion : the solution without UDAF is better because we don't need to sort the whole dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With fixed size array I wouldn't bother with `UserDefinedAggregateFunction` and use standard aggregations:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = Seq(
  (1, Seq(1.0, 3.0)),
  (1, Seq(3.0, 7.0)),
  (2, Seq(2.0, 4.0))
).toDF("id", "values")

df.groupBy("id").agg(array((0 until 2) map (i => avg($"values"(i))): _*))
```

```
+---+-------------------------------------+
| id|array(avg(values[0]), avg(values[1]))|
+---+-------------------------------------+
|  1|                           [2.0, 5.0]|
|  2|                           [2.0, 4.0]|
+---+-------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Save my day !!!