# How to obtain the average of an array-type column in scala-spark over all row entries per entry?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I got an array column with 512 double elements, and want to get the average. Take an array column with length=3 as example:

```
val x = Seq("2 4 6", "0 0 0").toDF("value").withColumn("value", split($"value", " "))
x.printSchema()
x.show()


root
 |-- value: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)

+---------+
|    value|
+---------+
|[2, 4, 6]|
|[0, 0, 0]|
+---------+
```

The following result is desired:

```
x.select(..... as "avg_value").show()

------------
|avg_value |
------------
|[1,2,3]   |
------------
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `avg` built-in function? https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@avg(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column

Comment: average over all rows per column, not avg for this column. What has length got do with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider each array element as column and calculate average then construct array with those columns:

```
val array_size = 3
val avgAgg = for (i <- 0 to array_size -1) yield avg($"value".getItem(i))
df.select(array(avgAgg: _*).alias("avg_value")).show(false)
```

Gives:

```
+---------------+
|avg_value      |
+---------------+
|[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]|
+---------------+
```

Comment: any other ways of doing this? this takes a long time to execute

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick for a constant sized array:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, avg, array
df = spark.createDataFrame([ list([[x,x+1,x+2]]) for x in range(3)], ['value'])
num_array_elements = len(df.select("value").first()[0])
df.agg(array(*[avg(col("value")[i]) for i in range(num_array_elements)]).alias("avgValuesPerElement")).show()
```

returns:

```
+------------------+
|avgValesPerElement|
+------------------+
|   [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]|
+------------------+
```

Thought I read pyspark. Leaving for pysparkers.

Answer (score 0):

Using **aggregate** may be faster!

```
n = 3
seqOp = (lambda x, y: [(x[i]*x[n] + y[i])/(x[n]+1) for i in range(n)]+[x[n]+1])
combOp= (lambda x, y: [(x[i]*x[n] + y[i]*y[n])/(x[n]+y[n]) for i in range(n)]+[x[n]+y[n]])
df.rdd.aggregate([0]*(n+1), seqOp, combOp).collect()
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46513007/how-to-compute-the-mean-by-index-of-an-array-column-in-a-dataframe) , you can try to restructure and aggregate:

```
df.groupBy("some_id").agg(array((0 until 3) map (i => avg($"value"(i))): _*).alias("avg_vector"))
```